# Retrofit 2 response body

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, retrofit2

I am trying to get a bearer token from Twitter's oauth.  I make a @POST to base url **https://api.twitter.com** which looks like this:

```
@Headers({ "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"})
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/oauth2/token") Observable<Result<BearerToken>> getBearerToken(
        @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

My **BearerToken** model class is:

```
public class BearerToken {
public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

@SerializedName("access_token")
String accessToken;
```

}

However, I am trying to parse the Result of `Result<BearerToken> bearer`, by calling `bearer.response().body().getAccessToken()`, but logcat says it is **null**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `Response` instead of `Result`?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: It's the only thing that seemed odd to me and checking the doc they also use `Response<T>` and not `Result`

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Wrong.  Not according to any samples I've seen, including u2020!

Comment: Turns out `Result` just wraps `Response`. You should check `error()` since "The response received from executing an HTTP request. Only present when #isError() is false"

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Nothing in error.